# JSON data types cannot be deserialized from a GraphQL query by using Ferry package

Tags: dart, graphql, ferry

I have this GraphQL query:

```
query QuoteRequests($page: Int!) {
  getQuoteRequestsList(page: $page) {
    vehicle
    body
    licensePlate
    vin
    quality
    currency
    items
  }
}
```

It generates this sample result:

```
{
    "data": {
        "getQuoteRequestsList": [
            {
                "vehicle": "1997 TOYOTA AVALON 4 DR ",
                "body": "Sedan",
                "licensePlate": "RHJ456",
                "vin": "XBGGDFYYREAXVJJJD",
                "quality": [
                    "GENUINO"
                ],
                "currency": "USD",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "uid": "74355f85-5312-9999-8acd-709ceccda00a",
                        "name": "Doble cero que es",
                        "description": "no me interesa",
                        "quantity": 11
                    },
                    {
                        "uid": "66db6fe0-1044-4d58-8454-5e51ab7a313f",
                        "name": "El arenero",
                        "description": "el duende verde",
                        "quantity": 2
                    }
                ]
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

The **items** data is a JSON type, and when trying to fetch that data by using [Ferry](https://pub.dev/packages/ferry) package with

```
client.request(GQuoteRequestsReq((b) => b..vars.page = 0)).listen((response) => print(response.data.toString()));
```

I get a Null result, but if I leave **items** out of the query, I get a no-null result. I have no problem if I run that query using the **HTTP** package.

Is this is an error from Package? or do I need to configure something?

Thanks.

### UPDATE 1

This is definitely an error because if I try to make a hot-reload in Flutter I get this error in debug console:

```
Reloaded 1 of 1700 libraries in 860ms.
E/flutter ( 2286): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Deserializing '[__typename, Query, getQuoteRequestsList, [{__typename: GetQuoteRequestsRecor...' to 'GQuoteRequestsData' failed due to: Deserializing '[{__typename: GetQuoteRequestsRecord, uid: 0bf6709f-7ab7-464e-8ee3-6a94e46f05...' to 'BuiltList<GQuoteRequestsData_getQuoteRequestsList>' failed due to: Deserializing '[__typename, GetQuoteRequestsRecord, uid, 0bf6709f-7ab7-464e-8ee3-6a94e46f057...' to 'GQuoteRequestsData_getQuoteRequestsList' failed due to: Deserializing '[{uid: 16870250-5acb-4c23-a7e4-f4e23bbd23ad, name: Doble cero que es, descrip...' to 'GJSON' failed due to: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String?' in type cast
E/flutter ( 2286): #0      BuiltJsonSerializers._deserialize
package:built_value/src/built_json_serializers.dart:178
E/flutter ( 2286): #1      BuiltJsonSerializers.deserialize
package:built_value/src/built_json_serializers.dart:124
```

It's clear it is fetching the expected result but it cannot deserialize properly, then it returns a null result.

Is there any workaround?

### UPDATE 2

I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70320441/955594) but I'm getting same error.

In my case, I've followed these steps, I've

- installed `built_value` package,
- edited `build.yaml` file,
- run the command `flutter packages pub run build_runner build`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer can be found in this [issue](https://github.com/gql-dart/ferry/issues/314).